# phonegap crash on "resume"

Tags: javascript, cordova

My phonegap application works great but there is a glitch when it is sent to the background or "paused". When focused is returned to the app a high percentage of the time the interface is frozen and then the application crashes a few seconds later. When relaunched it is working fine again.

Could anyone provide some information as to what could be causing this and where I should start trying to debug it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you applied any of the techniques found on http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494768/Debugging%20PhoneGap%20Apps ?

Comment: Yep, no kinda of logging helps because it's frozen on resume.

Comment: What version of Phonegap you using ?

Comment: 1.8.0 had a known issue much like this. If you are using1.8.0, please update to 1.8.1

Comment: I am using 1.8.0 thanks for the heads up I will try updating.

Comment: I know this is old but anyway: I currently have the exact problem with Phonegap 2.5 running ios 6.1.2. The cause for me is my audio which is using the Audio API. No solution yet!

Comment: More info about this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15192468/577306

Comment: Is your app doing any audio or video processing in the app? If yes, note that all of the video rendering and audio rendering has to stop right before going to background - there is method that will notify you right before the app goes to the background; where you can stop any audio/video processing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Cordova.plist or YourApplication-Info.plist (I don't remember exactly which one)
2. Create new option called "Application does not run in background" from dropdown list
3. Set to "YES"
4. ...
5. PROFIT!

Answer (score 0):

While not the answer but was still a valid solution, I could either change audio framework to HTML Audio or to Phonegaps Media object.

I've chosen the latter for the time being.